# Connection between Z-Score and Quasi Likelihood?

Tags: likelihood

Consider the Quasi-Likelihood function (I wrote it in the GEE context):

$$ Q(\beta; y) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \mu_i(\beta))^T V_i^{-1}(\beta, \alpha) (y_i - \mu_i(\beta))$$

where:

- $y_i$ is the response for the $i$-th subject,
- $\mu_i(\beta)$ is the mean response for the $i$-th subject,
- $V_i(\beta, \alpha)$ is the variance function for the $i$-th subject,
- $\beta$ are the fixed effects parameters, and
- $\alpha$ are the dispersion parameters.

Looking at the Quasi-Likelihood, I can see something which looks very similar to the Z-score (in matrix form): A Random Variable subtracted by the Expected Value of the Random Variable divided by the Variance.

This makes me wonder - is there any relationship between the Quasi-Likelihood and the Z-score? Perhaps the motivation exact form of the Quasi-Likelihood was chosen to resemble? Does this have something to do with the Central Limit Theorem - i.e. the Quasi-Likelihood is asymptotic normal because it is a sum of normalized Random Variables? (I am attempting to prove this myself and will show my work in another question)

Comment: The expression you have written is not what is called "quasi-likelihood" in generalized linear model theory. I guess that people can attach the prefix "quasi" to almost anything, but the squared residual expression you have written is usually called a Pearson statistic. It has also been called "pseudo-likelihood" in some papers.

Comment: E.g. https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/jchan/GLM/QuasiLikelihood.pdf page 2 -is this the same thing?

Comment: No, that is not the same thing. The USyd link you give describes the classical generalized linear model definition of quasi-likelihood. The $Q$ function in your question is instead the Pearson goodness of fit statistic.

Comment: my apologies, I will try and fix this